# Change Password Strength Indicator names?

Tags: filters, password

Is it possible to change the labels for "Weak, Medium, Strong" etc... in the Password Indicator that's used in the user profile? I've been asked to change the word "Weak" to "OK" since this level of passwords is acceptable for our subscribers. Is there a filter I can hook into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with this method. Is this good/bad? It's working, but I'd be interested in feedback in case this could have unexpected consequences.

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text'); 
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) { 
$translated = str_ireplace('Very Weak', 'Bad', $translated); 
$translated = str_ireplace('Weak', 'OK', $translated); 

return $translated; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to my function.php file in the child theme folder did it for me:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_strength_meter_localize_script' );
function my_strength_meter_localize_script() {
    wp_localize_script( 'password-strength-meter', 'pwsL10n', array(
        'empty'    => __( 'But... it\'s empty!', 'theme-domain' ),
        'short'    => __( 'Too short!', 'theme-domain' ),
        'bad'      => __( 'Not even close!', 'theme-domain' ),
        'good'     => __( 'You are getting closer...', 'theme-domain' ),
        'strong'   => __( 'Now, that\'s a password!', 'theme-domain' ),
        'mismatch' => __( 'They are completely different, come on!', 'theme-domain' )
    ) );
}
```

[**Source**](https://nicola.blog/2016/02/16/change-the-password-strength-meter-labels/)

Answer (score 2):

[This post on Web Tips](http://www.webtipblog.com/force-password-complexity-requirements-wordpress/) hooks into a few choice actions and filters to modify password strength allowances, but commenters seemed to have some trouble with it, so take this bit with a grain of salt.

```
// functions.php

add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'validateProfileUpdate', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'validateRegistration', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'validate_password_reset', 'validatePasswordReset', 10, 2 );

/**
 * validate profile update
 *
 * @author  Joe Sexton <joe.@webtipblog.com>
 * @param   WP_Error $errors
 * @param   boolean $update
 * @param   object $user raw user object not a WP_User
 */
public function validateProfileUpdate( WP_Error &$errors, $update, &$user ) {
    return validateComplexPassword( $errors );
}

/**
 * validate registration
 *
 * @author  Joe Sexton <joe.@webtipblog.com>
 * @param   WP_Error $errors
 * @param   string $sanitized_user_login
 * @param   string $user_email
 * @return  WP_Error
 */
function validateRegistration( WP_Error &$errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    return validateComplexPassword( $errors );
}

/**
 * validate password reset
 *
 * @author  Joe Sexton <joe.@webtipblog.com>
 * @param   WP_Error $errors
 * @param   stdClass $userData
 * @return  WP_Error
 */
function validatePasswordReset( WP_Error &$errors, $userData ) {
    return validateComplexPassword( $errors );
}

/**
 * validate complex password
 *
 * @author  Joe Sexton <joe.@webtipblog.com>
 * @param   WP_Error $errors
 * @param   stdClass $userData
 * @return  WP_Error
 */
function validateComplexPassword( $errors ) {
    $password = ( isset( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) && trim( $_POST[ 'pass1' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'pass1' ] : null;

    // no password or already has password error
    if ( empty( $password ) || ( $errors->get_error_data( 'pass' ) ) )
        return $errors;

    // validate
    if ( ! isStrongPassword( $password ) )
        $errors->add( 'pass', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Your password must contain at least 8 characters.' ); // your complex password error message

    return $errors;
}

/**
 * isStrongPassword
 *
 * @author  Joe Sexton <joe.@webtipblog.com>
 * @param   string $password
 * @return  boolean
 */
function isStrongPassword( $password ) {
    return strlen( $password ) >= 8; // your complex password algorithm
}
```

If you can't get the hooking route to work or if you have a custom login page, [this post on Tuts Plus](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-the-included-password-strength-meter-script-in-wordpress--wp-34736) has a handy tutorial for utilizing the existing script on your own forms.

Add to `functions.php`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'password-strength-meter' );
```

In your HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="password" name="password_retyped" />
    <span id="password-strength"></span>
    <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The script:

```
function checkPasswordStrength( $pass1,
                                $pass2,
                                $strengthResult,
                                $submitButton,
                                blacklistArray ) {
    var pass1 = $pass1.val();
    var pass2 = $pass2.val();

    // Reset the form & meter
    $submitButton.attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    $strengthResult.removeClass( 'short bad good strong' );

    // Extend our blacklist array with those from the inputs & site data
    blacklistArray = blacklistArray.concat( wp.passwordStrength.userInputBlacklist() )

    // Get the password strength
    var strength = wp.passwordStrength.meter( pass1, blacklistArray, pass2 );

    // Add the strength meter results
    switch ( strength ) {

        case 2:
            $strengthResult.addClass( 'bad' ).html( pwsL10n.bad );
            break;

        case 3:
            $strengthResult.addClass( 'good' ).html( pwsL10n.good );
            break;

        case 4:
            $strengthResult.addClass( 'strong' ).html( pwsL10n.strong );
            break;

        case 5:
            $strengthResult.addClass( 'short' ).html( pwsL10n.mismatch );
            break;

        default:
            $strengthResult.addClass( 'short' ).html( pwsL10n.short );

    }

    // The meter function returns a result even if pass2 is empty,
    // enable only the submit button if the password is strong and
    // both passwords are filled up
    if ( 4 === strength && '' !== pass2.trim() ) {
        $submitButton.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
    }

    return strength;
}

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // Binding to trigger checkPasswordStrength
    $( 'body' ).on( 'keyup', 'input[name=password1], input[name=password2]',
        function( event ) {
            checkPasswordStrength(
                $('input[name=password]'),         // First password field
                $('input[name=password_retyped]'), // Second password field
                $('#password-strength'),           // Strength meter
                $('input[type=submit]'),           // Submit button
                ['black', 'listed', 'word']        // Blacklisted words
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Weak" text is passed through `_x` function, which calls `translate_with_gettext_context`, so I would try the following:

```
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'wpse199813_change_password_indicatior', 10, 4 );

function wpse199813_change_password_indicatior($translations, $text, $context, $domain){

    if( $text == "Weak" && $context == "password strength")
        return "OK";

    return $translations;
}
```

Comment: Your code didn't work, but I was able to fix it with the 'ngettext' and 'gettext' functions. Your answer helped point me in that direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right in your theme localization file.

Open `*.pot` file and create the translations for labels you need, e. g. `OK` for `Weak`.

See `password-strength-meter` around line `#366` in `/wp-includes/script-loader.php` for the reference (but don't change there anything).

**Update**:

I've found the solution using jQuery for the similar problem, but you have to simplify that code to use only one password meter: [How to use wordpress default Password Strength Meter script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42596/how-to-use-wordpress-default-password-strength-meter-script). Also see `/wp-admin/js/user-profile.js` for reference because that solution is pretty old.

Comment: Would the theme localization apply only to the theme files? The password strength is in the core. Can you put a .pot file in the core that only translates that one word?